# osdelay function stm32

Tags: microcontroller, c, stm32, delay, stm32f4

I still work with stm32f407 and I have a question. When I write osDelay function for 2 seconds , it works 5 seconds. How can I fix this extra delay ? This osDelay function in cmsis_os.h library.

Comment: check clock frequency and configured/assumed

Comment: Your delay is not precise, find clock frequency as @Umar said and period of that frequency, and just multiply period*some_number to get approximately that 2 seconds you need.

Answer (score 1):

osDelay is a RTOS delay primitive that uses the RTOS Kernel Timer input clock frequency that YOU must provide in a configuration file that is RTOS dependent.
For CMSIS-RTX port the value is specified in the OS_CLOCK macro in the RTX_Conf_CM.c file.
For CMSIS-FreeRTOS port the value its specified in the configCPU_CLOCK_HZ in the FreeRTOSconfig.h file.
The osDelay primitive its relative precise (probably ~1ms) for what its meat to be used.
For 2 second delay osDelay(2000) will be "precise" 
Regards